# MongoDB group by and SUM by array

Tags: mongodb

I'm new in mongoDB.

This is one example of record from collection:

```
  {
    supplier: 1,
    type: "sale",
    items: [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("60ee82dd2131c5032342070f"),
        "itemBuySum": 10
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("60ee82dd2131c50323420710"),
        "itemBuySum": 10,
        
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("60ee82dd2131c50323420713"),
        "itemBuySum": 10
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("60ee82dd2131c50323420714"),
        "itemBuySum": 20
      }
    ]
  }
```

I need to group by TYPE field and get the SUM. This is output I need:

```
{
    supplier: 1,
    sales: 90,
    returns: 170
}
```

please check [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/w-6O_EbnQUm) for better understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `$match` - Filter documents.
2. `$group` - Group by `type` and add `item` into `data` array which leads to the result like:

```
[
  [/* data 1 */], 
  [/* data 2 */]
]
```

3. `$project` - Decorate output document.

   3.1. First `$reduce` is used to flatten the nested array to a single array (from Result (2)) via `$concatArrays`.

   3.2. Second `$reduce` is used to aggregate `$sum` the `itemBuySum`.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $match: {
    supplier: 1
  },
  
},
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$type",
    "supplier": {
      $first: "$supplier"
    },
    "data": {
      "$push": "$items"
    }
  }
},
{
  "$project": {
    _id: 0,
    "supplier": "$supplier",
    "type": "$_id",
    "returns": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": {
          "$reduce": {
            input: "$data",
            initialValue: [],
            in: {
              "$concatArrays": [
                "$$value",
                "$$this"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "initialValue": 0,
        "in": {
          $sum: [
            "$$value",
            "$$this.itemBuySum"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qzhT4TNG-lV)

Comment: Side note, as you are querying document with `supplier:  1`, it's fine to group by `type`. However, when no longer query for `supplier:  1`, then the result after group by `type` only won't be correct.

Comment: I will use this code with supplier ID for every request. thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      supplier: 1
    },
    
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$ID",
      "supplier": {
        "$first": "$supplier"
      },
      "sale": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              "$eq": [
                "$type",
                "sale"
              ]
            },
            "then": {
              "$sum": "$items.itemBuySum"
            },
            "else": {
              "$sum": 0
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "returns": {
        "$sum": {
          "$sum": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                "$eq": [
                  "$type",
                  "return"
                ]
              },
              "then": {
                "$sum": "$items.itemBuySum"
              },
              "else": {
                "$sum": 0
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0,
      supplier: 1,
      sale: 1,
      returns: 1
    }
  }
])
```